async/await is not yet supported in Client components
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { getPricingPage } from "@/sanity/queries/page";
import { WebsiteForm } from "@/components/sections";

export const PricingPage = async () => {
 const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
 const data = await getPricingPage();
 const { hero, subscription, price } = data;
return (
 <>
   <div>
     <div className="flex flex-col space-y-6 items-center md:space-y-12">
       <Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Click Me</Button>
     </div>
   </div>
   <WebsiteForm open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen} />
 </>
);
};

export default PricingPage;

I am building this NextJs app with sanity, and I am trying to fetch the data from Sanity, and it was working just fine before, but then, I added the useState hook to open the WebsiteForm, and I am receiving an error every time I click on the button saying "async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding 'use client' to a module that was originally written for the server."
I do understand what the error implies, but fixing it is the problem.
Your help would be extremely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

If your PricingPage component is indeed a page component, I'd really recommend it keeping it as a server component. That way you can still use server-side fetching and metadata generation.
Your best bet in this case is to separate the rendering logic into another component and keeping the data fetching in your page component. This way, the fetching component remains a server component and you get to manage state in the visual component.
Basically, something like this:
In page.tsx:
import { getPricingPage } from "@/sanity/queries/page";
import { PricingForm } from "./PricingForm";

export const PricingPage = async () => {
 const data = await getPricingPage();

 return (
   <PricingForm data={data} />
 );
};

export default PricingPage;

And in PricingForm.tsx:
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { WebsiteForm } from "@/components/sections";

export const PricingForm = async ({ data }) => {
 const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
 const { hero, subscription, price } = data;

 return (
   <>
     <div>
       <div className="flex flex-col space-y-6 items-center md:space-y-12">
         <Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Click Me</Button>
       </div>
     </div>
     <WebsiteForm open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen} />
   </>
 );
};


Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly!! God bless!
